# ORACLE synonym table describe constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, sqlplus, synonym

I would like to see the constraints defined in a synonym of a table.

When a type

`SQL> DESCRIBE table_name;`

It shows me only the number of each column, the not null flag and the size. How can I know all the constraints for each column? How can I know also if the synonyms are either public or private?

Thanks,
Alvaro.

---

**SOLUTION**

With @Aramillo helps and adapting it to my needs, I figure out how to do it. I want to see the Constraints defined for a table but not according to the USER. There are two options, with [ALL_CONSTRAINTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm) and [ALL_CONS_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1035.htm).

`ALL_CONSTRAINTS` has not the column COLUMN_NAME in order to know the column's name which the constraints is set to. `[ALL_CONS_COLUMNS]` has.

Query:

`SELECT * FROM all_cons_columns WHERE table_name = 'table_name';`

About the private or public synonym, as the links above say,

> ALL_CONSTRAINTS/ALL_CONS_COLUMNS describes constraint definitions on tables accessible to the current user.

So I guess if it shows data either the synonym is public or you are the correct user for the private synonym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query gives you all constraints of a synonym with name `REGION_SYN_P` for the current user:

```
SELECT constraint_name,
       c.table_name,
       synonym_name,
       S.OWNER
  FROM user_constraints C, all_SYNONYMS S
 WHERE     C.TABLE_NAME = S.TABLE_NAME
       AND S.TABLE_OWNER = C.OWNER
       AND S.Synonym_name = 'REGION_SYN_P'
```

If you want to know if is public or not, you just have to check owner column, in case it's a public synonym the owner will be `PUBLIC`.

You can use `all_constraints` instead `user_constraints` if you need query the constraints in other schemas.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the following is for Oracle.
Query the so called static data dictionary:
[oracle constrains](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1042.htm#REFRN20045)

work it out with 
DBA_CONSTRAINTS
USER_CONSTRAINTS
or
DBA_CONS_COLUMNS
USER_CONS_COLUMNS

[stack link for Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879217/display-names-of-all-constraints-for-a-table-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: There is no `information_schema` in Oracle. And there is no `use` statement.

Comment: When I type INFORMATION_SCHEMA:`SQL> use INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
unknown command beginning "use INFORM..." - rest of line ignored.` as @a_horse_with_no_name says, it seems that there is not such table in Oracle (neither `use` statement)

Comment: and instead of `use` what is used with Oracle?

Comment: click on the link I provided (oracle constrains)
but you will have to understand the data dictionary which is the equivalent of information_schema

Comment: -1 for not getting rid of the MySQL specific code in a question tagged Oracle

Comment: as requested.
you can keep your -1. I'm not gonna cry ;)