# get constraint name by column name in oracle database

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

How to get unique constraint_name of The corresponding column in oracle database?

in other words I want  to get constraint name by column name.

pseudo query for this question:

```
select constraint_name from table_name tname where tname.column_name = 'columnName';
```

is this possible?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [How to fetch the system generated check constraint name of table column in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34932419/1509264) but with the added restriction of only getting `UNIQUE` constraints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Oracle dictionary views `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` or `USER_CONS_COLUMNS` (if you want to restrict it by column type - i.e. unique or primary key constraints - then you can join in `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` or `USER_CONSTRAINTS`):

```
SELECT acc.constraint_name
FROM   ALL_CONS_COLUMNS acc
       INNER JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS ac
       ON ( acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME )
WHERE  ac.OWNER        = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME'
AND    ac.TABLE_NAME   = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
AND    acc.COLUMN_NAME = 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME'
AND    ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ( 'U', 'P' )    -- Unique or primary key constraints
```

or:

```
SELECT ucc.constraint_name
FROM   USER_CONS_COLUMNS ucc
       INNER JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS uc
       ON ( ucc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = uc.CONSTRAINT_NAME )
WHERE  uc.OWNER        = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME'
AND    uc.TABLE_NAME   = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
AND    ucc.COLUMN_NAME = 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME'
AND    uc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ( 'U', 'P' )      -- Unique or primary key constraints
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
select CONSTRAINT_NAME from  USER_CONS_COLUMNS
where table_name='YOUR_TABLE' 
and column_name='YOUR_COLUMN'
```

Comment: This will get all constraints for the column - not just the `UNIQUE` constraints.

Comment: thanks a lot , but as I say,I want  get the  only 'unique' constraint name,