# How to change the size of a column with FOREIGN KEY constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

There are two tables

```
DEPT (
    DEPT_ID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    DEPT_NAME VARCHAR2(10)
);

COURSE (
    COURSE_ID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    COURSE_NAME VARCHAR2(15),DEPT_ID NUMBER(5),
    FOREIGN KEY(DEPT_ID) REFERENCES DEPT
)
```

I want to change the size equal to `5` of the column `DEPT_ID` which has a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

I tried changing but it gives error:

> ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type

Which is because it violates the foreign key constraint.

**I didn't supplied any name to the foreign key while creating tables**. So how can I do it without dropping any table.??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to do the following:

- drop the foreign key constraints to the tables (you can use `alter table drop constraint`).
- change the data types in all the tables (you can use `alter table modify column`)
- add the foreign key constraints back (`alter table add constraint`)

This doesn't require dropping any tables.

Comment: I used the command  `Alter table course DROP CONSTRAINT foreign key;` but it gives error  `invalid ALTER TABLE option`  !!. I didn't give any name to foreign key during table creation.

Comment: @RajeevSingh . . . If you didn't give an explicit name, you have to search through the constraints to find the right name for the foreign key.  There is one; it is just gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

You have to drop the foreign key constraint first. Then execute the command you mentioned. Then add back the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, you need to drop the foreign key constraint. As for the name of constraint, i know solution for 'sql server' for oracle below link may help. [Display names of all constraints for a table in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879217/display-names-of-all-constraints-for-a-table-in-oracle-sql)