# Exploring Primary Key and Foreign Key in order to Construct ERD

Tags: oracle, entity-relationship

I just imported data into an oracle database from a dump file. But I want to know constraints to enable me to make an Entity Relationship diagram and its links.

I used

```
select * from cat;
```

to get the description of each table. But this is not showing constraints and looks cumbersome to explore all tables like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display names of all constraints for a table in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879217/display-names-of-all-constraints-for-a-table-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: SQLDeveloper has a data modelling tool built-in and it's free. I would suggest giving that or Toad (not free) a try before attempting it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should query `USER_CONSTRAINTS` and `USER_CONS_COLUMNS` to find such a data.

Also, if you use `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026)), you'll be able to extract DDL used to create tables & constraints.

However, consider using a GUI tool which enables you to "draw" tables and automatically queries metadata in order to graphically display information you're interested in. One of these is TOAD which, in its "Database - Report" menu offers the "ER diagram". I believe some other tools have it as well.